# Capybara save_and_open_page with third party JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

Using Capybara I get alot of javascript errors due to cross origin policies regarding external javascript (Twitter widget API and typekit font).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: http://www.whateverorigin.org/

Comment: How would I incorporate that into Capybara tests?